# How do I create a directory and get started with Django project?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I've researched and read much on this subject but I am stuck.

This tutorial I am doing told me to create a code directory which will be my  per se. So I used the mkdir code to create the code directory.

So in windows powershell it looks like this:

PS C:\python27\scripts\code>

The tutorial tells me to go to my code directory which I am already in and to use the django-admin.py start project tango_with_django_project.

I am also using windows obviously since I am using Windows powershell so I have read up on how to create the start project.

It can't find it under the code directory so I just "cd" back to 
\script and typed in the admin.py again and a the CLI black box popped open and then shut quickly. The tutorial then tells me I should have created a new directory tango_with_django_project.

When I "ls" I get:

```
Directory: C:\python27\scripts


 Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
 ----                -------------     ------ ----
 d----         7/22/2015  11:56 PM            code
 -a---          7/4/2015  12:03 AM      92041 django-admin.exe
 -a---          7/4/2015  12:03 AM        132 django-admin.py
 -a---          7/4/2015  12:03 AM        333 django-admin.pyc
 -a---          7/2/2015   1:39 AM      92008 easy_install-2.7.exe
 -a---          7/2/2015   1:39 AM      92008 easy_install.exe
 -a---          7/1/2015  10:01 PM      95564 pip.exe
 -a---          7/1/2015  10:01 PM      95564 pip2.7.exe
 -a---          7/1/2015  10:01 PM      95564 pip2.exe
```

so I have successfully created something within scripts but I believe I need a directory and not whatever the A stands for under mode.

The tutorial then says:

You’ll now notice within your workspace is a directory set to the name of your new project, tango_with_django_project. Within this newly created directory, you should see two items:

•Another directory with the same name as your project,
tango_with_django_project; and

•A Python script called manage.py.

I do not see a script called manage.py. How do I access or find that script if I am doing everything right so far?

Comment: It might be a typo in your question, but make sure your type `startproject` and not `start project` in the `django-admin.py startproject ...` part.

Comment: Don’t call `django-admin.py` from your console. Either call `py django-admin.py` or just `django-admin` (which will call the exe). Also, you really shouldn’t have your Django project *within* the scripts directory of your Python installation. Put it in your documents or something.

Comment: Wow after all the detail and descriptions I made that simple startproject was right! It was not a typo.. my project showed up as a directory

Comment: @poke, if I try to put it somewhere else.. it wont let me. Tells me I need to make sure the path is correct or is not recognized. for some reason it only creates new projects under scripts

Comment: @RandyGoldsmith added my response as an answer. @poke is also correct though - to fix this issue you need to append `C:\python27\scripts` to your `PATH` environment variable (and then start a new session of PS). You can edit `PATH` using the GUI (`Edit environment variables for your account`). Note the values are `;` separated on windows.

Comment: @DanielB I looked up how to edit and create new paths.. I have no idea what append means or what its doing but when I get there.. C:\python27 is the only thing that's there.. if im adding scripts to it what does that do?

Comment: `PATH` is where you computer looks for executables when you run a command. You need to add `;C:\python27\scripts` to the end. It should have happened automatically when you install python. If you're not sure don't mess with it before doing some research - it has the potential to break other things.

Comment: @DanielB I was able to add it to my path. But also in the tutorial I am working on it actually requires us to use the .py scripts instead of the other one. I know in the CLI using .py calls upon whatever you have for that file/script. I don't necessarily know what you mean by exe.

Comment: @poke Why isn't it proper to put Django projects within scripts dir? The tutorial I am working on leads us to do that but if its not standard I want to know why and also how would I be able to put it in another directory because I am only able to put it into ../scripts

Comment: @RandyGoldsmith The scripts directory is supposed to contain *executable* utilities from your Python installation; that’s also why it’s often added to the PATH. It’s not meant for project-specific stuff but only for global things that are managed by your Python installation (usually using pip), Also, depending on where you install Python, the directory is not writable without admin access. Instead, place project specific things in a separate folder, e.g. in your user’s documents folder, or on the desktop even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're typing `django-admin startproject tango_with_django_project` and not `django-admin start project tango_with_django_project` (note there shouldn't be a space in `startproject`).